# calling C# function from onblur of listbox

Tags: asp.net, listbox

How to call a C# function on the `onblur event` of the `listbox`?

I am using `listbox.Attributes.Add("onblur","CSharpfuncname")..`

Please Suggest

Comment: check this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1680231.aspx/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my knowledge you can't do this directly(calling server side or c# function onblur event) see [MSDN FOR LISTBOX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx) when you look for events you don't have any event relevant to focus out or on blur, to achieve this you have to implement [Page Methods](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109) or [Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx) [CallBack](http://brijbhushan.net/2010/12/19/exploring-client-callback/). Look for these three links regarding Page Methods and Client CallBack hope it will help you out.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could make an ajax call which in turn can call your C# method

JQuery:

```
$("#listboxId").blur(function(){//Put your AJAX call here});
```